# PTIJ: Am I betrothed to her?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I sent a woman a gift through PayPal. My email is harry@nekudeshetli.com. She used the money to buy something over a peruta. Do I need to give her a get for her to be free to marry others?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Is anyone else going to point out the irony in Clint Eastwood using an email address that starts with [Harry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Harry)?

Comment: @Bachrach44 I bet you're wondering if he fired six shots, or only five. ;)

Comment: I'm missing something. Have you correctly spelled the email address? You wrote nekudeshet, not mekudeshet. Is that a typo? If so, please edit. If what you typed is correct, then your question seems incorrect and irrelevant.

Comment: Mods, this should be closed as psak seeking, not as old PTIJ.

Answer (score 4):

If your e-get lands in her email inbox even if she doesn't read it, that should be sufficient.
You'll need to send the email with PGP to have it digitally signed as an unsigned get is not valid. Some have been using 'DocuSign' but it would seem you must use 'AidUsign' which requires your webcam to recognize two faces besides your own as you send it.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend if she was using a good voice manager on the computer with which she received the email. She would also have to program her computer to use your voice to read out the email address properly. Otherwise, she might think that it is from someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in order to do so, you will need to change your email address to Harry@megureshetmime.ni, which means you have to move to [Nicaragua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ni).

Comment: I don’t think the inyan is that he himself has to move there, but we say שלוחו של אדם כמותו.

Comment: Exactly, so therefore even if his Shliach is from Nicaragua, it is still not good enough, he himself needs to be from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but you didn't say kdaas Moshe viyisrael, so you're in trouble anyway